# Use ActiveSync to sync old mails

Tags: synchronization, hotmail, activesync

I'm trying to build a ActiveSync client application.
I have a test Hotmail account, which has mails from the past 6 months, most of them unread.
Hotmail uses ActiveSync v2.5.
I tried the Sync command, but I'm able to get only new mails, the old  (> 3 months) mails don't appear!

Am I missing something or is this how it works?

[Edit: Including the request and response Xml to make it more clearer]

Initial Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>0</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001</CollectionId>
            <WindowSize>512</WindowSize>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>000000000{813672f0-cc63-4308-9a33-4e8c1d0f351e}0</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001</CollectionId>
            <Status>1</Status>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>000000000{813672f0-cc63-4308-9a33-4e8c1d0f351e}0</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001</CollectionId>
            <GetChanges />
            <WindowSize>512</WindowSize>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>000000000{13704907-A726-4149-8186-E3EEE98D9918}1</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001</CollectionId>
            <Status>1</Status>
            <Commands>
                <Add>[Contains email details]</Add>
            </Commands>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Also, the same code works great for a GMail account (which uses ActiveSync v12.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the Hotmail servers respond differently to different devices.
I modified the User-Agent value sent to the server to Apple-iPhone/705.18 and it started working!

Comment: Wow. I would never have expected that to be the case, but good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not passing a [`FilterType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg709713%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) element which would restrict the range of objects returned.

Secondly, watch for a [`MoreAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650876%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) element in the [Sync response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee178414%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) which would indicate that you haven't yet received all the objects from the server.

[Edited based on comments]

Comment: I'm not using a FilterType element. From the link, "If the FilterType element is omitted, **all objects are sent from the server without regard for their age**."

Comment: You're right, looks like it's optional. In that case, are you receiving the MoreAvailable element in the response to indicate that that more objects (beyond what was initially returned) are available?

Comment: I've added the request-response Xml to my question. MoreAvailable element isn't received.